# What is the best way to show that the method modifies the argument in c#?

Tags: c#, methods

I have a method which besides some other actions also modify one of the arguments.
For example:

```
public void DoSomeStuffAndModifyList(List<int> list)
{
   ...
   list.Add(newElement);
}
```

It looks for me that the name of the method is not enough for pointing on this. May be the whole approach is wrong or there could be *ref* or *out* used?

Comment: Does it really need to modify the list?  Why can't you *return* the element you would have added?  Then it's up to caller to do with it what they will.

Comment: Why mutate the list at all? Return a new list with the modifications.

Comment: what is the problem here ? "it looks for me that the name of the method is not enough for pointing on this" - is not clear enough

Comment: The fact that you have "And" in the method name suggests that the method has two responsibilities. Split it into two methods, each with one responsibility.

Comment: it's already splitted. This the method that calls those 2 methods. so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a descriptive name for your method / arguments

```
public void FillItems(string foo,IList<Item> itemsToFeed)
```

Comment: It's in these cases that I really like Obj-C's method signatures being parameter-based.  `-(void)AddItemsFor:(NSString*)user ToList:(NSMutableArray*)list)`

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `ref` unless it is actually necessary.

If your method is

```
void DoSomething(List<int> list)
{
    list.Add(whatever);
}
```

Adding `ref` is not useful. You are doing nothing that requires it, only adding additional complexity for no benefit, and possibly making the method harder to reason about for a maintenance programmer.

Use `ref` when your method can actually change `list` by *pointing it to something other than the original list*. This can be a completely new list, another existing list, or null. *And* only use `ref` when you want this change to be visible at the caller.

For your method, explore refactoring it so that maybe adding or removing items from the list is not necessary. After you've done this, absolutely name the method appropriately. After you have done *that*, utilize the method and parameter summary comments to convey information you think is useful.

```
/// <summary>
/// Describe the method andhere
/// </summary>
/// <param name="list">Describe what's relevant about the parameter here.</param>
```

*Don't* abuse the `ref` keyword, *do* appropriate refactoring, *do* use documentation.

Answer (score 0):

use `ObservableCollection<T>` and fire `CollectionChanged` event when it changed
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx

or you can make your method as exentsion method like that

```
public static List<int> DoSomeStuffAndModifyList(this List<int> list)
{
 ...
 list.Add(newElement);
 return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am slightly confused on your question.  Are you asking how to name your methods?

You should break your your actions into different methods.  I wouldn't worry to much about the method that calls these actions.  As long as it is descriptive enough, that should be fine.

As John Saunders said, split your methods for single responsibility.

```
public List<int> GetList()
{
   //return list
}

public void ModifyList(List<int> list)
{
  //Modify list, you could return if you wanted to.
}

//Call 2 methods
List<int> list = GetList();
ModifyList(list);
```

Comment: It's already broken on 2 methods, this is the method that calls those methods.

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu why do you need this  method to call these 2 methods? Is `DoSomeStuffAndModifyList` have some logic beside calling these methods?

Comment: To follow up with what Micropressor said, if all your DoSomeStuffAndModifyList is calling 2 methods, why not just directly call the 2 methods after each other.

Answer (score 0):

How about returning a new list:

```
public List<int> DoSomeStuff(List<int> list)
{
    ...
    return list.Concat(new[] { newElement });
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Concat` be more appropriate here, if you're trying to mimic the behaviour of `List<T>.Add`?

Comment: that was my favorite choice, but I'm not sure that it's descriptive enough, it pretends that the argument is not modified inside the method but the new value is returned

Comment: @LukeH, you are correct. `Concat` would be more adapted to mimic the adding.

Comment: @Hun1Ahpu, exactly, that's why it is descriptive. Like all LINQ extension methods do. They return new values.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomeStuffAndModifyList(this List<int> list)
    {
       ...
       list.Add(newElement);
    }
)
```

And to call it:

```
var gradeList = new List<int>();
gradeList.DoSomeStuffAndModifyList();
```